# 'Collapsing' 'RepeatColumns' property of ASP CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, html

I use the RepeatColumns of an ASP CheckBoxList to create three columns in a list of genres.  This usually works OK but occasionally when the page loads the columns collapse.  This seems to happen randomly and across all browsers.  I do use OutputCache.

Has anyone noticed this behavior before?

This is a snippet of the code:

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td width="66%" style="padding-left:4px">Genres:</br>

    <asp:CheckBoxList RepeatColumns="3" CssClass="chkChoice" ID="CheckBoxList_Genres" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Action</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Comedy</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Classics</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Documentary</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Drama</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Fantasy</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Foreign</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Independent</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Kids</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</td>
```

In response to the comment, this is the rendered html:

```
    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres" class="chkChoice"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$0" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_0">Action</label><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$3" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_3">Documentary</label><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$6" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_6">Foreign</label><br /><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$1" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_1">Comedy</label><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$4" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_4">Drama</label><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_7" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$7" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_7">Independent</label><br /><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$2" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_2">Classics</label><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$5" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_5">Fantasy</label><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_8" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList_Genres$8" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres_8">Kids</label></span>
```

Comment: Can you post the renderd HTML? It should be rendered as a table with each check/label pair in each cell.

Comment: I posted the rendered html.  I just noticed that when it *does* work, it includes the following before the span -- any idea why this is sometimes missing?: <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList_Genres" class="chkChoice" border="0">

Comment: @alpheus: See my answer below. I'm puzzled about the randomness of the layout in your case though.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind tabulating the checkboxlist, add `RepeatLayout="Table"`.

E.g.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList RepeatColumns="3" CssClass="chkChoice" 
  ID="CheckBoxList_Genres" runat="server" 
  RepeatLayout="Table" >....
```

Comment: RepeatLayout="Table" is the default.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to have helped.  As I noted in the comment above, sometimes the <table...> is rendered and it displays correctly; sometimes it is not and it does not.

Comment: @Phaedrus: I thought so too, really puzzled by the inconsistent rendering.

Comment: @alpheus: Do you have any codes in the code-behind that involves the CheckBoxList other than reading the data from it?

Comment: I read the checked items and I also sometimes set items to be checked like this:                 CheckBoxList_Sources.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;